# How to Loadtest ActiveMQ with NMS –Publisher and subscriber?

Tags: c#, .net, jmeter, performance-testing

How to Loadtest ActiveMQ with NMS –Publisher and subscriber?
in JMeter I Could JMS Subscriber and JMS publisher.
Is there any tool or plug in to test through JMeter .. ?
(Trying to publish and subscribe in .NetFrame work (C#)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [JMeter Performance Tests](http://activemq.apache.org/jmeter-performance-tests.html) page at the ActiveMQ website? I believe it contains all the answers.

- Add [ActiveMQ client jars](http://activemq.apache.org/initial-configuration.html) to [JMeter classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
- Restart JMeter to pick the .jars up
- Add [JMS Publisher](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher) and [JMS Subscriber](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Subscriber) to the Test Plan and configure them according to your test scenario.

Check out [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) article for more details if needed

Comment: Yes, i don't want to test through JMS , want to test the NMS(.net ,c#).